# Cannot build Boost Wave example

Tags: c++, boost

These are my (ones of the many) steps in order to build *list_includes* example, leading to nowhere:

1. Download the latest boost from the official site (currently it's 1.67.0, but I also tried 1.66.0), extract it
2. $ ./bootstrap.sh
3. $ ./b2 --with-wave --with-program_options --with-filesystem --with-system --with-thread --with-date_time

   *I took these dependencies from the Jamfile inside the build directory*
4. $ ./b2 install
5. $ cd libs/wave/samples/list_includes/build

   *Just for demonstrating the path*
6. $ ../../../../../b2

or

5. $ cd libs/wave/samples/list_includes
6. $ g++ -o list_includes list_includes.cpp -lboost_wave -lboost_program_options -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lboost_date_time

No matter how I do it, I get this (template arguments are omitted for the sake of readability):

> undefined reference to `boost::wave::cpplexer::lexertl::new_lexer_gen<>::new_lexer(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<> const&, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<> const&, boost::wave::util::file_position<> const&, boost::wave::language_support)'
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Now I don't understand why it's complaining about cpplexer as it's the part of the library itself - and the library is built and specified in the command line! Thanks for any help/advice.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm stuck with this myself. I'd appreciate if  you shared your solution.

Comment: @sehe I posted my solution

Comment: Thank you so much for identifying this issue. We have (separately) repaired the problem - I just happened to Google it :( Next time try filing an issue [here](https://github.com/boostorg/wave/issues).

In the meantime, is `list_includes` working for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this nightmare... The traitor is `lexertl_interface.hpp` !

Insert in there the following include: `#include <boost/wave/cpplexer/re2clex/cpp_re2c_lexer.hpp>`

And change lines 70-71:

> return new_lexer_gen::new_lexer(first, last, pos, language);

to:

> return boost::wave::cpplexer::new_lexer_gen::new_lexer(first, last, pos, language);